# Cannot best fit a local HTML file with CSS file into WebView in Android

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

I have a simple html file containing a table and a relevant css part inside. I am trying to fit by width my local html file in a real device of 4.5' inch but whatever I tried has no result. For some pixels in off the screen.

In order to display my local html file I use the following:

```
public void ShowHtml(){

    WebSettings webSettings = statshtml.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    statshtml.loadUrl("about:blank");
    statshtml.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    statshtml.loadData(str, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
}
```

I have tried the

```
  x.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  x.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

  x.setInitialScale(1);

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no"/>
```

but nothing happens and my question is should I change something in the following css part?

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-b3ft{font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif !important;;background-color:#f56b00;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-eli4{font-weight:bold;background-color:#f56b00;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-m7of{font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;background-color:#bbdaff;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-9hbo{font-weight:bold;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}}</style>
```

thank you

Comment: try adding style width:100% to body or tag which is going out of scope. Also share complete html and how webview is placed in code